# Render HTML in Jupyter notebook on EMR

Tags: python, html, amazon-s3, amazon-emr, jupyter-lab

I need to render a HTML from a cell in Jupyter Notebook on EMR cluster.
Things that have not worked so far:

1. using IPython display

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
example = '<html><head><title>Dummy</title></head><body><h1>Dummy</h1></body></html>'
display(HTML(example))
```

that returns `<IPython.core.display.HTML object>`

2. the file into notebook location on s3, with hopes of it then being clickable (and viewable) in jupyterlab interface. which does not happen. the file is visible after restarting the notebook, and in case it overwrote existing file, the file is restored to original state.

Any way with either opening the html in new browser tab or new jupyterlab tab or in a cell is acceptable.